# Storing the json data from a url into database in the cordova

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, sqlite, cordova

I want to store the json data into my database within cordova . Im using angular js to retrieve the json data . one of my json data is a image source which is in string format (base 64). please help me to store the data into cordova DB

My json looks like :
{"PlayList":[{"videoId":"bMvZymcZAFE","playlistTitle":"UAE Exchange India Briefing","playlistId":"PLPQxCdv2_-qjo0yucR6FmKzC-DqvFx83L","videoTitle":"UAE Exchange India Celebrates Customer Loyalty Month","videoPosition":"1","imgSrc":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAUDBAkICAgICQkGCAgHCAcHCAcHCAgHBwcHBwgHBwcIBwcHChALBwgOCQcHDRUNDhER"}],"errorMsg":"SUCCESS","errorFlag":"S"

script :

```
                  <script>
                    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
                         app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
                       $http.get("http://www.uaeexchangeindia.com/wp-content/themes/uaexindia/youtube-links-rand-mobapp.php?playlistId=PLPQxCdv2_-qjo0yucR6FmKzC-DqvFx83L&limit=0")
                       .then(function (response) {

                             $scope.names = response.data.PlayList;});
                       });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cordova Supports storage mainly in 3 ways - Local storage, websql and indexDB.

I would suggest to use pouchDB instead, This will take care of storing in available db, and you can store data in the same json format. [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/)

OR else

you can go ahead and use sqlite plugin. As you are using angular for your application its advised to use ng-cordova . [Link to ng-cordova plugin for sqlite](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/)

Comment: punchDB link is not loading..!

Comment: Their site is down, i guess. download it from here https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/releases/tag/5.4.2

Comment: pouchdb link is back online

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found my solution ..!
 Here is the code

```
      var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
      $.each(obj.PlayList, function (index, i) 
  {
          var videoId = i.videoId;
          var imgSrc = i.imgSrc
      save(videoId,imgSrc );
       });
     },
         error:function()
         {
           alert("error");
          $(".load_div").hide();
                }
            });


    function save(videoId,imgSrc){

     var today = new Date();
     var dd = today.getDate();
     var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
     var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

      if(dd<10) {
          dd='0'+dd
              }

     if(mm<10) {
           mm='0'+mm
              }

      today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
```

var myDB= window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo",10485760);

```
             myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {

             transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS YOUTUBE_VIDEO (id primary key, videoID text, imgSRc varchar)', [],
                function(tx, result) {

                                     },
                function(error) {
               alert("Error occurred while creating the table.");
               });
                 });


                 myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
                 var executeQuery = "INSERT INTO YOUTUBE_VIDEO (videoID,imgSRc) VALUES (?,?)";
                 transaction.executeSql(executeQuery, [videoId,imgSrc]
                 , function(tx, result) {

                 var newImage = document.createElement('img');
                 newImage.src = "data:image/png;base64,"+imgSrc;
                 document.getElementById("img").innerHTML = newImage.outerHTML;


                 },
                 function(error){
                 alert('Error occurred');
                 });
                 });
                 myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
                 transaction.executeSql('SELECT * FROM YOUTUBE_VIDEO WHERE id = ?', [1], function (tx, results) {

                 }, null);
                 });
```

}